# how to take the nth value from a column based on the value of another column (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

any help here?!
let's suppose I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
A | B

1 | b

1 | b

1 | a

2 | a

2 | b

3 | b

3 | c

3 | d
```

I want to get the first occurrence for each value of the colA
it would be something like

```
A | B

1 | b

2 | a

3 | b
```

then catch the second occurrence
something like that:

```
A | B

1 | b

2 | b

3 | c
```

after 3 occurrence

```
A | B

1 | a

2 | NULL

3 | d
```

any tips on how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index = 'A', columns = df.groupby('A').cumcount(), values = 'B', aggfunc = sum)
result = [df1[col].reset_index(name='B')  for col in df1.columns] #this will give you the list of df's
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
[   A   B
 0  1   b
 1  2   a
 2  3   b,
    A   B
 0  1   b
 1  2   b
 2  3   c,
    A    B
 0  1    a
 1  2  NaN
 2  3    d]
```